# What is this large device labelled 'Telefunken Datenspeicher' and how does it work?

Tags: hardware, identify-this-peripheral

[image: That‘s the device.]

[image: This is the „keyboard“ that is connected to it]

We found this device in our school. Does anyone know what this can do exactly, and how it could work?
We managed to input values into the bit storage on the top, but nothing more. Can we calculate things by using the registers?

It would be already helpful to know what the symbols like AD, EX, AS,… mean. Or the dial with just 7 and 8 on it.

Comment: Some more background info could be helpful. Where did you find it? How old do you think it is? Do you know German?

Comment: It looks like some of this is the same as the Telefunken Datenspeicher seen on [this page](https://www.computermuseum-mannheim.de/comp_verschiedenes.htm)

Comment: @OmarandLorraine We really don‘t know anything about it. My teacher said, it was already there when he came to the school, and it’s definitely 50 years or older. Yes, I know German, we are in a German School. Telefunken is the company and Datenspeicher means data storage. By Google Lens I already found out about the page you linked, and I think it is exactly the same device. However, the page leads no additional information about it.

Comment: It looks definitely something pedagogic. The section with the A and B register looks like a serial ALU. The part with the combined AND and OR gates is probably the ALU, where the functions can be selected throught light green/gray lines starting at the left side. I suppose the console on the lower picture can be used to set values in the A..F memory and the registers.

Comment: @Poldi It does always help to add all information already gathered.  That said, it's obviously an (very simple) serial 8 bit ALU with two registers and an external storage of 6 words. The logic diagram of the 'cpu' is right there using original DIN symbols. Labeling is mostly clear when using German :))

Comment: Is that a full rotary dial for the 7 and 8?  Vrrp-tic-tic-tic-tic-tic-tic-tic-tic ?   Weird.

Comment: The sections with A and B seems to be shift registers formed with S-R flip flops. The input AB and BA would allow to transfer the contents of register A to B and from B to A in 8 cycles. Cannot figure out the part that uses input AD, ET and EX that forms something that resemples a decoder (but not quite) because the lines do not seem to connect to flip flop A7, although it may be that they would also be connected to the R and S inputs of that flip flop.
They might be JK flip flops instead of RS... difficult to tell from that "schematic"

Comment: @gusbro check here for [DIN 40700 symbols](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logikgatter#Typen_von_Logikgattern_und_Symbolik) to better understand the drawing.

Comment: @Geo... Why? A rotary dial is a perfect timing source for 1..10 clock pulses in a speed well to do with relay logic or alike.

Comment: @Raffzahn, Yes, I saw your answer after I posted that comment and you are right.  It _never_ occurred to me what a perfect clock generator a rotary dial would be.  :-)

Answer (score 62):

### It's a Demonstrator for an ALU and Memory.

It's a serial ALU with registers, data path and a 6 byte storage, falling short to be a CPU.

---

An [ALU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_logic_unit) (German as well [ALU](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetisch-logische_Einheit), sometimes 'Rechenwerk') is a function unit to combine two inputs, usually called A/B, according to defined rules into an output (called C).

The whole setup is somewhere half way between an ALU, a CPU and a computer as it additionally features registers and memory and data paths between them, but falls short of having a program sequencer or storage. Except for the memory it's best described with the German term [Rechenwerk](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rechenwerk) - [Execution Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Execution_unit) in today's view (although that being defined slightly different).

If it had an instruction unit, all of the buttons would be control lines from an instruction decode stage ([Befehlsdecoder](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Befehlsdecoder)) (or a horizonal code word) setting the behaviour of each element for one execution cycle ([Befehlsausführung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Befehlszyklus#3._Befehl_ausf%C3%BChren)).

---

***Please Note* All of the below are assumptions made from the pictures shown** so take it with an appropriate amount of caution.

---

> We found this device in our school.

Neat, would love to have something like that at our [museum](https://blog.computeum.org/).

> Does anyone know what this can do exactly, and how it could work?

It seems like a simple Serial ALU. Operation get put in at AT/ET/EX, Data from A register or O/L and B-Register.

### Schematics are DIN 40700 based

The best way to look up the exact function would be reading the schematics, which are printed right on top. The equations are rather straight forward as it's build from only AND, OR and FlipFlop. The schematic language is used according to DIN 40700 (*1):

**[AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AND_gate)** ([Und](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Und-Gatter))

[image: AND Gate]

**[OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OR_gate)** ([Oder](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oder-Gatter))

[image: OR Gate]

**[FlipFlop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics))** ([Bistabile Kippstufe](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flipflop))

[image: JK-FlipFlop]

*(Most likely of the shown [JK type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)#JK_flip-flop))*

> We managed to input values into the bit storage on the top, but nothing more. Can we calculate things by using the registers?

As far as I can tell, yes.

> It would be already helpful to know what the symbols like AD, EX, AS,… mean. Or the dial with just 7 and 8 on it.

### Operator Table

First estimate for all buttons

- Top Row - **Memory Access**

  - **<kbd>SETZEN</kbd>** -> Wert Speichern (Set)
  - **<kbd>A</kbd>**..**<kbd>F</kbd>** -> Speicheradresse (Storage Address Selection)
  - **<kbd>LÖSCHEN</kbd>** -> Löschen (Clear)
- Second Row - **Function**

  - Block 1

    - **<kbd>A-SP</kbd>** -> A - Speicher (A - Storage)
  - Block 2 - **ALU Operation**

    - **<kbd>AD</kbd>** -> Addition (Addition)
    - **<kbd>ET</kbd>** -> Et (&) (See Below)
    - **<kbd>EX</kbd>** -> EXclusive oder (exclusive or)
  - Block 3

    - **<kbd>UMKEHREN</kbd>** Richtung Umkehren (Reverse Direction) (See Below)
- Third Row - **Register Transfer Operation**

  - Block 1 Data - **Operation on A**

    - **<kbd>AS</kbd>** -> A Setzen/Speichern (Set A)
    - **<kbd>AR</kbd>** -> A Rückführung (Cycle A back to A)
    - **<kbd>AB</kbd>** -> A nach B (Move A to B)
  - Block 2 Data - **Operation on B**

    - **<kbd>BS</kbd>** -> B Setzen/Speichern (Set A)
    - **<kbd>BR</kbd>** -> B Rückführung (Cycle B back to B)
    - **<kbd>BA</kbd>** -> B nach A (Move B to A)
- Fourth Row

  - Left (Main) block - **Data Input**

    - **<kbd>1</kbd>**..**<kbd>128</kbd>** -> Input Data Value
  - Right (Below Dial) - **Single stepping**

    - **<kbd>O</kbd>** -> Single Bit Data Input (See Below)
    - **<kbd>L</kbd>** -> Single Bit Data Input (")
    - **<kbd>TAKT</kbd>** -> Tact, one clock pulse

**<kbd>ET</kbd>** is Latin for 'and' and the [German name](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Et-Zeichen) for the '&' symbol, commonly known as 'Und' (And) Symbol or 'Kaufmännisches Und' (Commercial And) or  'Firmen-Und' (Company-And) as it's often used in company names.

**<kbd>UMKEHREN</kbd>** is 'Reverse Direction' (*2). A mystery  first. Considering it being located in the function control row and coloured black like **<kbd>A-SP</kbd>**, not white like the ALU functions, it might be about memory transfer direction. That would make sense by assuming that pressing **<kbd>A-SP</kbd>** connects lines O/L to the memory and **<kbd>UMKEHREN</kbd>** defines direction. When not pressed A transfers to memory, pressed transfers memory to A.

Connecting the memory for reading *and* writing at O/L als resolves why there are no other connections visible used for writing (*3). Except that the circuitry as drawn does not allow to read A at O/L. So while the operation seems plausible, the location memory writes are connected is still unclear.

The Dial works as clock circuit. A rotary dial emits 1..10 of pulses according to the value dialled (10 = 0). thus 7 and 8 are there to emit 7 or 8 clock pules. The other values are simply blocked as they make no sense with an 8 bit system.

On the main table O/L are data entry lines to feed the A register an external value. Most likely those two buttons enable loading of the value selected at the fourth row (or from memory).

Combined with the **<kbd>TAKT</kbd>** (tact) those buttons may work as a single step clocking instead of using the dial to handle a full 8 bit word at once. If that's true, then pressing **<kbd>TAKT</kbd>** will give a single clock pulse, while **<kbd>O</kbd>**/**<kbd>L</kbd>** can provide a single bit input value - if needed according to transfer mode setting (see above). This also explains why they are located at the dial - aka the central clock generator:)

### Main Table

The main table is structured in three blocks:

- B-Register at the top
- ALU in the middle (kind of framed by black clock lines)
- A-Register on the bottom

All logic symbols are according to DIN 40700. All connections are colour coded using

- Red/Green for *Data*
- Black for *Clock*
- Yellow for *ALU Operation*
- Blue for *Data Transfer Control*

Buttons are coloured

- White for Data and Control Input for ALU and Registers
- Black for other all functions and

Most of the symbols at the keyboard correspond directly to the same inputs visible on the main table, except for the register name:

- A-Register -> Alu-Register, i.e. target for computation (and usually as well a source)
- B-Register -> Secondary value
- U-Register -> Übertrag (Carry)

In addition the symbols O and L on the main board seem to correspond with the data output of the memory block, as well as the single step block at the operators panel.

### Memory Table

The memory table seems to be an optional add-on as the main Block only marks a single external input (O/L) and no corresponding output. At least when going by schematics. Otherwise O/L could as well be used as output to memory.  Then again, mechanically the setup seems to fold into a single carrying case, right?

### Function

The **one bit ALU** is formed by a network of AND/OR gates visible in the middle combining the operation (AD/ET/EX) with data input from A and B input (top 4 red/green lines below the B-register, coming from A/B registers) and a carry input (only enabled for additions).

C output comes from the second stage OR gates (the wide ones) and goes to the A register. A carry is created by two AND gates looking at the data value for that bit

The ALU works serial, one bit at a time. Each operation results in a new bit (shifted into A) and a carry value stored at U-Register to be used with the next data bit(s).

The **A-Register** holds the last result of any ALU operation and serves as A input for ALU operation. It can be feed from four sources

- Reload (feedback) of it's previous value (Enabled by AR)
- Load from B (enabled by BA)
- ALU result (lines from those wide OR-gates)
- Load from external source (lines O/L)

The later is most likely the way data is entered from console or memory. As mentioned the way (connection) data is transferred *to* memory is still unclear. It could as well work using O/L, but then the schematic is missing that part.

The **B-register** register can only be fed from the A-register or its previous value.

Both registers also feature **Input Enable Function**. Here xS (x=A or B) allows a register is to be set with a 'new' input value. This is important as serial operation is by default destructive, i.e if no 'new' value is selected the register will be cleared afterwards.

### Operation

Operation *seems* rather straight forward, **although it might need a few trials to get it right**. Examples

Before each example/step unset all buttons.

1. Load A from Keyboard

   - Set value on **<kbd>1</kbd>**..**<kbd>128</kbd>** buttons
   - Set **<kbd>AS</kbd>** so A gets loaded
   - **<kbd>Dial 8</kbd>** and enjoy
2. Transfer A to B

   - Set **<kbd>AB</kbd>**
   - If the value in A is tobe retained

     - Set **<kbd>AS</kbd>** to enable setting of A
     - Set **<kbd>AR</kbd>** to reload A with A
   - **<kbd>Dial 8</kbd>** and watch
3. Add B to A

   - Set **<kbd>AD</kbd>** to select ALU function for addition
   - Set **<kbd>AS</kbd>** to store the result in A
   - If the value in B is to be retained

     - Set **<kbd>BS</kbd>** to enable setting of B
     - Set **<kbd>BR</kbd>** to reload B with B
   - **<kbd>Dial 8</kbd>** and listen

And so on...

Of course fun only starts by combination - like adding two numbers is done by sequence of 1,2,1,3. You're program and sequencer of this CPU, so do your job :)

Sounds like several very engaging class hours to analyze and document that device. Lucky kids!

---

At that point several experiments should be done to validate above assumptions. For example storing to memory with and without  **<kbd>AR</kbd>** pressed to see if the write data is taken directly from A output or at/near O/L.

---

#### Sidenote:

What I loved most is how clear and self defining the labelling is. Not just because of straight language, but equally by *not* using any self referencing technological terms - that kind of words "everyone knows", but in fact only experts in that area know - if at all - and use with laymen because of that assumption. Misuse being just a quantum leap away. Not so with this device.

---

*1 - The symbols might be a bit unusual for people grown up using US style symbols or younger folks more familiar with those square IEC boxes. German Wiki has a [comparison table](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logikgatter#Typen_von_Logikgattern_und_Symbolik).

*2 - Interpreting this as reversing or inverting bits doesn't make much sense, as there is no logic visible, neither for reversing nor inverting all bits. Also reversing would be 'Umdrehen', while inverting is 'Invertieren' in German

*3 - Too bad as it would prohibit any exchange operation.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write this all out! I will check if it works next week.

Comment: @Poldi Added description of what seems to be a single step mode, allowing to monitor bit by bit operation. Also, it would be nice if you could stick a permanent note to the device with [pointer to us](https://blog.computeum.org/) - just in case your school needs to get rid of the device :))

Comment: @Poldi  Please keep us informed about the results. Also, could you please try to look up any markings, type or Fabriknummer. Possibly taking a picture of everything remarkable?

Comment: The **AND** gate picture has a nice opaque white background. The **OR** and **FlipFlop** however, are transparent, making them very hard to read on my dark themed version of this page.

Comment: I think, Block 3 "Umkehren" is for complementing, flipping all bits to negate a value (in ones' complement representation)

Comment: "Umkehren" means reverse, so flipping the bits sounds right to me too.

Comment: @masswerk Yeah, good first assumption, thought about it, but for one Umkehren is 'Reverse' but bit flipping in German is 'Invertieren', second there is no logic visible to reverse bit sequence nor one to invert them and last, it's part of the memory block, where that function doesn't make much sense, or does it? It's really hard to solve some of what's seen without trying out. I hope Poldi keeps us in loop.

Comment: @masswerk I gave it another thought. In fact, 'Umkehren' means reverse direction, which _does_ make a lot of sense when considering that CPU to memory transfer is directional - to memory or from memory. So that button is to be seen in conjunction with 'A-SP'. A-SP is enabling  the CPU-Memory connection, while 'Umkehren' reverses the direction (from write to read). This also makes it need only a single two wire (plus clock) connection using the well defined O/L lines.

Comment: @JackAidley Not really. 'Umkehren' is reverse (ones own) direction, while flipping bits would rather be 'Umdrehen' (turn sth. around).

Comment: @Dúthomhas Feel free to add renderings that work _equally well_ for your display settings.

Comment: @JackAidley "Umdrehen" is more like reverse order. ("umkehren" is the literal equivalent tp Latin "invertere"/invert, which may have been deemed too technical for an educational application.) – Technical terms in German are actually quite terrible, either too unspecific or overly specific… ;-)

Comment: But what is good for? It must have had some actual usage.

Comment: @Chozang It's a demonstrator to teach students how an ALU and CPU works .Isn't that the best usage possible? Spreading Knowledge!

Comment: I tried a lot of things you wrote today. Unfortunately, when I dial the 8, we can hear ticks from the machine, but nothing else happens, the lights stay the same. I think it might be broken. We are probably going to open the device and look if there is any damage.

Comment: @Poldi Thanks for the update. Where exactly is your school located? Just asking in case :))

Answer (score 17):

A and B are two shiftable 8-bit registers. They form a serial ALU.

U is the Überlauf-Register (carry).

"Takt" is the clock signal. It shifts both registers, after 8 clocks the operation is complete.

All of the 9 white buttons in the two middle rows are present in the diagram, and they are control signals for the ALU.

"AB" transfers register A to register B, and "BA" transfers register B to register A. "AS" should switch between shifting and counting (or maybe shifting and nothing), the S probably means "Schieben".

"AR" enables the cyclic retransmission of the value back into A (Rückführung?).

Same for "BS" and "BR".

"AD", "ET" and "EX" select the ALU operation, performed by the first four, the middle two or the last two terms of the AND-OR combination, respectively. "AD" produces a 1 when an odd number of the A,B,U inputs is 1, so that's an addition. "ET" produces a 1 when both A and B are 1, so that's an "and" operation. Similarly, "EX" is exclusive or.

I can't see the label for the inputs of the A register above "AS" and "AR", potentially these come out of of the "Datenspeicher" (storage) registers selected by A to F.